# Calculate percentage of a normal distribution using standard deviation

Tags: normal-distribution, standard-deviation

The weight of bags **normally distributed** with a standard deviation of $5$ $kg$.
Given that $50$% of the bags weigh more than $55$ $kg$, how can we calculate the percentage of bags that weigh less than $65$ $kg$?
My try:
We know that $P(X>55)=50$%, but know we need to calculate $P(X<65)$, but I'm a bit stuck here.

Comment: Hint: Normal distributions are symmetric, so if $P(X>55) = 50\%$, what do you know about the mean and median of your distribution? Then, how many standard deviations away is 65 kg from your mean?

Comment: @AmaanM Then we know that also $P(X<55)=50$% but how can I use the standard deviation to calculate $P(X>65)$?

Comment: First you need to figure out how many standard deviations 65 is from the mean, then you can use a [$Z$-table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_normal_table) or a statistical calculator to see what the probability of being that far away from the mean is.

Comment: @AmaanM How do you calculate it formally?

Comment: If you're looking for an explicit formula to calculate it using arithmetic, there isn't one. The [cumulative distribution function for a standard normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Cumulative_distribution_function) can't be written in terms of elementary functions, and always includes an integral that has to be calculated numerically. The best you can do is a table of values or a statistical software.

Comment: How was the table created?

Comment: Never mind; found it. It involves integrating the probability density function, which I wouldn't attempt except numerically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$ P\left(X<65\right)=P\left(\frac{X-55}{5}<2\right)=P\left(Z<2\right)=\phi \left(2\right)=97.72 $$